# Add space between title and plot in Bokeh

Tags: bokeh

How can I add space (or padding) between `title` and plot in bokeh?

There seem to be a `offset` attr but that offsets only horizontally. I also tried using `<br/>` and `\n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
p.title.vertical_align = 'top'
```